# Is there any private api to detect camera access by different apps on iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi

I need to implement an app that monitors camera use i.e. which app used camera (started/stopped) on iPhone.

my app is going to run in background using apple's background multitasking feature for voip and navigators.

I can use private api as my client doesn't need this app on appstore.

Thanks.

Comment: can you use jailbroken phones, or does this have to work on non-jailbroken devices?

Comment: @Nate, non jailbroken devices only.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this private framework:
https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-/tree/master/ImageCapture.framework

It has some interesting classes (including ICCameraProperties with property locked)